# how to place set of datas in a div using for loop

Tags: php, css, arrays

My Array

```
   $images = array(
    'images/logo.png',
    'files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg',
    'default/img/noimage.png',
    'default/img/default-avatar.png',
    'images/logo.png',
    'files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg',
    'default/img/noimage.png',
    'default/img/default-avatar.png',
    'images/logo.png',
    'files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg'
   );

@for ($i=0; $i < count($images) ; $i++)
    @if($i%5 == 0)
        <div class="{{$i}}">
    @endif
        <img src="{{URL::to(''.$images[$i])}}">
    @if($i%5 == 0)
        </div>
    @endif
@endfor
```

Here I need to generate a div each 5 images.. i.e.,

first 5 images should be in one div and another (next) 5 images should be in another div..

**Now I get something like this**

```
<div class="0">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/images/logo.png">
</div>
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/noimage.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/default-avatar.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/images/logo.png">
<div class="5">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg">
</div>
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/noimage.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/default-avatar.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/images/logo.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg">
```

**But I need like this**

```
<div class="0">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/images/logo.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/noimage.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/default-avatar.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/images/logo.png">
</div>
<div class="5">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/noimage.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/default/img/default-avatar.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/images/logo.png">
    <img src="http://localhost/girija/eshop/public/files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg">
</div>
```

How should I get this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change loop like this:-

```
$images = array(
    'images/logo.png',
    'files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg',
    'default/img/noimage.png',
    'default/img/default-avatar.png',
    'images/logo.png',
    'files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg',
    'default/img/noimage.png',
    'default/img/default-avatar.png',
    'images/logo.png',
    'files/product_image/asansam-dongle-asan-sam-dongle-P688075T.jpg'
   );
<div class="0">
@for ($i=1; $i < count($images) ; $i++)
   <img src="{{URL::to(''.$images[$i])}}">
    @if($i%5 == 0)
       </div><div class="{{$i}}">
    @endif
@endfor
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since $i starts from 0 you chave to change your condition

```
@for ($i=0; $i < count($images) ; $i++)
@if(($i+1)%6 == 0)
    <div class="{{$i}}">
@endif
    <img src="{{URL::to(''.$images[$i])}}">
@if(($i+1)%6 == 0)
    </div>
@endif
@endfor
```

Answer (score 1):

by using [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
foreach(array_chunk($images,5) as $sub_images){
    echo "<div>";

    foreach($sub_images as $image){
        echo '<img src="$image"/>';
    }

    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $flag = 1;    
   @for ($i=0; $i < count($images) ; $i++)
        @if($flag%5 == 0)
            @if($i == 0)
                <div class="{{$i}}">
              @else:
                 <div class="{{$flag}}"> 
            @endif
        @endif
            <img src="{{URL::to(''.$images[$i])}}">
        @if($flag%5 == 0)
            </div>
        @endif
    @endfor
```